# Spring custom annotation for caching

Tags: spring, caching, annotations

I've used spring declarative annotation based caching approach. Here is how I've used it,

```
@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "T(org.mifosplatform.infrastructure.core.service.ThreadLocalContextUtil).getTenant().getName().concat(#username)")
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException { //method body }
```

This annotation looks very lengthy. I've tried to use a custom key-generator but the issue is when I define a key in the annotation,the custom key generator not get invoked.

So now I am trying to use a custom spring annotation as a workaround. But I was unable to find a good reference to start off. Basically I need to add a context aware parameter to the key (the tenant Identifier).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked Spring docs on [using custom annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-stereotype)?

Comment: @dimchez yes. But in my case, need to alter each and every key by adding a context aware parameter to the key. Spring docs on custom annotations does not provide that much details on how to do something like that.

Comment: You could use a custom key generator and annotate the parameters of the method you want to use for key generation, if you don't want all.

Answer (score 0):

Key has to be a static variable. It cannot be a runtime evaluation.
You need to override the CacheManager and then do the modification. Below is an example where I extend HazelcastCacheManager which in turn extends spring's Cachemanager

```
public class MyCache extends HazelcastCacheManager {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Cache> myCaches = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Cache>();

    public MyCache(){
        super();
    }


    public MyCache(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance){
        super(hazelcastInstance);
    }
    @Override
    public Cache getCache(String name) {

        String tenant = org.mifosplatform.infrastructure.core.service.ThreadLocalContextUtil).getTenant().getName();
        Cache cache = myCaches.get(tenant.concat("#").concat(name));
        if (cache == null) {
            IMap<Object, Object> map = getHazelcastInstance().getMap(tenant.concat("#").concat(name));
            cache = new HazelcastCache(map);
            Cache currentCache = cesCaches.putIfAbsent(tenant.concat("#").concat(name), cache);
            if (currentCache != null) {
                cache = currentCache;
            }
        }

        return (Cache)cache;
    }
```